# using mysql_real_escape_string to cleans my queries

Tags: php, mysql

Is this the best way to do it?

Should I do this to every value in every query? GET and POST?

Is `addslashes(mysql_real_escape_string())` overkill?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 6):

If you're using mysql_query() then yes, mysql_real_escape_string() is the best way. And yes, you have to apply it to every parameter you mix into your sql statement. E.g.

```
$query = "
  SELECT
     x,y,z
  FROM
     foo
  WHERE
    a = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['a'], $mysql) . "'
    AND b = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['b'], $mysql) . "'
 ";
```

But you can also use prepared statements, e.g. with the [pdo](http://php.net/pdo) module. The parameters are transferred apart from the sql statement and therefore do not require escaping. It's more secure (since you can't forget the escaping or doing it wrong/for the wrong charset), often faster and very often even simpler than mixing the parameters into the statement. e.g.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', '..', '..');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("
  INSERT INTO
    foo (x,y,z)
  VALUES
    (:x,:y,:z)
");

$stmt->bindParam(':x', $x);
$stmt->bindParam(':y', $y);
$stmt->bindParam(':z', $z);

// insert all records (0,0,0) ... (0,1,0) ... (9,9,9)
for($x=0; $x<10; $x++) {
  for($y=0; $y<10; $y++) {
    for($z=0; $z<10; $z++) {
      $stmt->execute();
    }
  }
}
```

edit: and addslashes(mysql_real_escape_string()) is not only overkill but also wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a mysql connection already established in your script to use mysql_real_escape_string().

**Have you tried PDO?**
It prevents mysql injection attacks automatically.

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$default_dbname", $dbusername, $dbuserpassword);

$st = $db->prepare ('SELECT * from my_table WHERE owner= ? and dog = ?');
$st->execute (array('Bob', 'Rex'));

$data = $st->fetchAll();
```

Might want to use [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)() on output though.